# How many combinations of coins add up to \$20

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We have four coins

- Coin 1: $0.10
- Coin 2: $1.00
- Coin 3: $1.00
- Coin 4: $1.00

How many ways can we get $20.00 from these coins?

My attempt:

I started by counting the total number of ways for each coin to reach $20.00

- 200 ways for coin 1
- 20 ways for coins 2, 3, and 4.

I now have an equation, a + b + c + d + e = 200

We want to get the total number of solutions without any constraints

$\dbinom{200+5-1}{5-1} = \dbinom{204}{4}$

Then I found the number of solutions with the constraint that the coin must be $\leq$ 20. The total number of solutions with coin > 20 can be determined by purchasing 21 coins and leaving 181 at most to buy.

$\dbinom{181+5-1}{5-1} = \dbinom{185}{4}$

The final solution is:

$$\dbinom{204}{4} - 3 \times \dbinom{185}{4} $$

Comment: If only four coins, why five vars a,b,c,d,e?

Comment: 'e' represents the difference between 200 and the number of coins purchased.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $200$ ways for coin 1.  If the twenty dollars consists solely of coins of type 1, there will be $200$ of them, but that's only one way, isn't it?  In fact the number of coins of type 1 bust be a multiply of $10$, so there are only $21$ choices for the number of coins of type 1.

Comment: @saulspatz I thought I could solve the problem using constraints. I wanted to take the total number of options, then remove the smaller constraints from that total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a multiple of 10 number of coins of type $1$. Hence, in effect we have four types of coin of \$ $1$ and desire non-negative solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=20$, which by the stars and bars problem is $\binom{23}{3}$.

Comment: Very neat.  I went through adding up the the stars and bars answer if there are $10k$ coins of type $1$, for $k=0,1,\dots,20$ and eventually ended up with ${23\choose3},$ but it never clicked that I could shortcut all that.

Comment: Thanks, @saulspatz.